# Is there an R function for Log Weibull distribution?

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I log-transformed my data and I attempted to fit multiple distribution including the weibull and gamma distribution. I used the fitdist() function in the fitdistrplus library. I wanted to find the expected value using the Weibull distribution in a given range using the PDF of the distribution. For the gamma distribution, it was easy to write the formula because there's a function called 
dlgamma which gives me the PDF of the log-gamma distribution. I was wondering if there's a similar function in R for the log-weibull distribution?

Comment: See `?Distributions` for a list of available distributions built into R.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
dweibull(x, shape, scale = 1, log = FALSE)
```

Comment: That would give me the PDF of the distribution but I'm looking for the log PDF of the distribution.

Comment: you are right, is not sufficient to put the parameter log = TRUE?